# Deleting Negative Point from an array of arrays

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to delete brackets that contain a negative number

```
list={{1,-1},{2,1},{5,6},{3,-0.0012}}

new list={{2,1},{5,6}}
```

How can I achieve that other than using `Drop` because I would like to apply this to much longer list with randomly placed negative numbers

Comment: Select the ones that are positive: `Select[list, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &]`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility

```
 Cases[list, x_ /; AllTrue[x,Positive] :> x ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a particular reason for `RuleDelayed` instead of just `Rule`?

Comment: @ercegovac Rule of thumb I use is this: If pattern name (`x` in this case) shows on the left, and also on the right side, then use `:>` , else use `->`

Comment: Ok, since I always look whether pattern evaluates or not, I was wondering if there is some speed difference between rule and rule delayed that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pick[#, AllTrue @Positive /@ #]& @ list
Pick[#, FreeQ[_?Negative] /@ #] & @ list
Select[#, AllTrue @ Positive] & @ list
Select[#, FreeQ[_?Negative]] & @ list
Cases[_?(AllTrue[Positive]@#&)] @ list
DeleteCases[_?(AnyTrue[Negative]@#&)] @ list
```

all give

> {{2, 1}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 0):

```
list[[PositionIndex[Positive[list]][{True, True}]]]
```

> {{2, 1}, {5, 6}}