# How to create patterns for DeleteCases / Cases / Select: deleting elements of a list, from the condition of a negative element in a column

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I've been trying to create a simple and "human readable" instruction for deleting elements from a list with an specific pattern.

I have the following list and I would like **to delete the elements** containing a **negative number** on the **second column**.

```
In[1]:= list = {{1,2},{3,-4},{-5,6},{7,8}};
```

I've found a nice solution in this question. However, this eliminates any element with a negative number.: [Deleting Negative Point from an array of arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157541/deleting-negative-point-from-an-array-of-arrays)

```
In[2]:= DeleteCases[_?(AnyTrue[Negative]@#&)] @ list
Out[2]= {{1,2},{7,8}}
```

My **desired output** would be:

```
Out[X]=  {{1,2},{-5,6},{7,8}};
```

Could maybe someone **recommend a source** where to learn **advanced pattern construction**?

*I've seen was involving underscores `_`, like: `{_,_Negative}`, but I'm not really clear on how to use it within `DeleteCases` functions. I found a nice [presentation](http://spindynamics.org/relaxation_engine/pattern_matching_intro.pdf) with slight details, but maybe a wider explanation would be handy.*

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, {_, _?Negative}]`

Comment: Works amazingly! Could you write it as an answer? @MarcoB

Comment: Done! I've added a little bit of context. Hopefully it will be helpful

Comment: `list /. {_, x_} /; x < 0 -> Nothing`

Comment: `Pick[#,UnitStep[#[[All,2]]],1]&@list` or (more 'human readable'?) `Pick[list,NonNegative@list[[All,2]]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were right that such a pattern would involve `_` (i.e. [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)) and a [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) (`?` for short):

```
DeleteCases[list, {_, _?Negative}]
Cases[list, {_, _?NonNegative}]
```

Above we are looking for a list of two elements, the second of which should return `True` when `Negative` or `NonNegative` is applied to it.

---

`Select` is slightly different because it is not pattern-based, but instead it uses a selector function:

```
Select[list, #[[2]] >= 0 &]
```

---

As a note for future reference, when you find yourself using your own function instead of a built-in like `Negative` in the pattern test, wrap it in parentheses to avoid precedence issues. In this case, for instance, you could have written `# < 0 &` instead of `Negative`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {_, _?(# < 0 &)}]
```

If you try it without the parentheses, you will not get what you expect because `PatternTest` has higher precedence than `Function`.

Comment: Or `Select[list, #[[2]] >= 0 &]` or `Cases[list, {_, _?NonNegative}]`

Comment: @Bob Good point, he had indeed asked for those other approaches as well. I'll add those

Comment: @Nikodem Are you sure you are using `list` as defined in the OP? Your code does nothing on that list.

Answer (score 5):

In such a simple case, @MarcoB's and @BobHanlon's answers are the way to go. In other words, use a pure function that tests a part of the desired element of each sublist, as in

```
Select[list,#[[2]]>0&]
(*{{1, 2}, {-5, 6}, {7, 8}}*)
```

However, it is interesting that some functions use different constructs. For example `Count` operates differently. For me, to preserve readability in those, I need to give a name to the sublists and create a conditional expression:

```
Count[list,sublist_/;sublist[[2]]>0]
(*3*)
```

This counts all the sublists, conditional on (`/;`) their second element being positive. The alternative, which is not readable if the sublists become complex, is to use patterns all the way, as in

```
Count[list, {_, _?NonNegative,___}]
```

This counts sublists with two or more elements, the second one of which is positive. Bob can probably explain this difference between `Select` and `Count` in a way that makes sense.